# Stop video when a modal is closed (videojs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, video.js

I use videojs plugin to customize a video player.

I have 30 modals with one different video in each modal (Youtube, Dailymotion, Vimeo).

I added two buttons next/prev to pass between each modal (modal always open).

All work fine. Each video is well displayed.

But I have two problems :

1. Each time I switch on a new modal is displayed the video is automatically played.
2. When I close a modal the video continue to be played.

For the excerpt of my code I used the ID `#popin-1` but each modal have a different ID `id="popin-1", id="popin-2", id="popin-3", id="popin-4"`

The links of each modal look like this :

```
<a href="#" class="btn-open" data-modal="popin-1">Open my modal</a>
```

The HTML code of each modal :

```
<div id="popin-1" class="popin__item">
    <div class="popin__wrapper btn-action">
        <div class="popin__inner">
            <a href="#" class="btn-close btn-action"></a>
            <div class="popin__canva">
                <div class="popin__video">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-next"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn-prev"></a>
                    <div class="popin__video-container">
                        <video
                        id="vid-1"
                        class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
                        controls
                        autoplay
                        width="640" height="264"
                        data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "autoplay": true, "fluid": true, "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "http://my-video-url.com"}] }'
                        >
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popin__content">
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And finally my js function. I tried

```
$('.btn-open').each(function(i, el) {
        var modal = $('#' + $(el).attr('data-modal'));
        var overlay = $('.popin__overlay');
        var close = $('.btn-action');

        var player = videojs('popin__item');

        function removeModal() {
            modal.removeClass('show');
            overlay.removeClass('show');
            $('body').removeClass('no-overflow');
            modal.player.pause();
        }

        function removeModalHandler() {
            removeModal();
        }

        $(el).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            modal.addClass('show');
            overlay.addClass('show');
            $('body').addClass('no-overflow');
        });

        close.click(function(e) {
            if($(e.target).hasClass('btn-action')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                removeModalHandler();
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: `$('video').map(function(i,e){ e.pause(); })`

Comment: To solve the Youtube autoplay, simply don't set autoplay to true.

Comment: I dont see modal.player defined..

Comment: @imvain2, I set autoplay to false, and I have the same issue :-(

Comment: @dandavis, where exactly can I put your code ?

Comment: inside of whatever event/function closes the modal.

Comment: @dandavis, I tried in the removeModal() function, unfortunatelly that don't work

Comment: if it uses an iframe, set the frame's src to "about:blank"

Comment: @dandavis, in fact I use videojs to customize my players. And videojs use <video> tag

Comment: if it uses the <video> tag, my first snip should work, but you said it doesn't, therefore it must be an iframe, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap modal you should be able to use this code.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events